# Spring Expression Language (SpEL) for json access with list

Tags: spring, spring-el

I'm trying to understand why this doesn't work?

```
  context.addPropertyAccessor(new JsonPropertyAccessor());

  Object j = mapper.readTree(
"{\"foo\": {\"bar\": [ { \"fizz\": 5, \"buzz\": 6, \"doo\": 9 }, {\"fizz\": 7}, {\"fizz\": 8} ] } })");

System.out.println(evaluate(j, "foo.bar.![doo == 9]"));
```

It always prints:

```
[false, false, false]
```

I need to check if any of the doo contains a 9.

Comment: What is the method `evaluate`?

Comment: `foo.bar[?(@.doo==9)]` gives you all `bar`s that have `doo==9`. If you need just true or false then `foo.bar[?(@.doo)].doo==9`

Comment: private static Object evaluate(Object target, String expression) {
        return parser.parseExpression(expression).getValue(context, target);
    }

Comment: The above expression gives me an exception.Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [foo.bar[?(@.doo==9)]] @10: EL1059E: @ or & can only be followed by an identifier or a quoted name

Comment: I thought you're using jsonPath https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/spel.html#built-in-spel-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need use SPEL necessarily you can do it easily with [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

Include dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use the `JsonPath` and query:

```
Srgin json = "{\"foo\": {\"bar\": [ { \"fizz\": 5, \"buzz\": 6, \"doo\": 9 },
    {\"fizz\": 7}, {\"fizz\": 8, \"doo\": 6} ] } })";

JSONArray array = JsonPath.read(json, "foo.bar[?(@.doo==9)]");

// now array is a List of size 1, since second "doo" is not equal 9
// using array.get(0) you can get first object as a HashMap<String, Object>
```

By the link mentioned above you can find more details about JsonPath queries.

---

If you still need to integrate JsonPath with SPEL you can add parsing function to the evaluation context. Fortunately you already use spring-integration which has `JsonPathUtils` class with `evaluate(String, String)` method.

```
StandardEvaluationContext evaluationContext = new StandardEvaluationContext();
Method method = BeanUtils.resolveSignature("evaluate", JsonPathUtils.class);
evaluationContext.registerFunction("jsonPath", method);

String json = "{\"foo\": {\"bar\": [ { \"fizz\": 5, \"buzz\": 6, \"doo\": 9 }, " +
            "{\"fizz\": 7}, {\"fizz\": 8, \"doo\": 7} ] } })";
evaluationContext.setVariable("foo", json);    

ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("#jsonPath(#foo, 'foo.bar[?(@.doo>6)]')");
Object result = expression.getValue(evaluationContext);
//now result contains still the same JSONArray
```

---

And finally I figured out the reason of your issue. First of all: guess what returns the expression `foo.bar.doo`? It's not a String or Integer value. It returns an instance of `ToStringFriendlyJsonNode`. So `doo==9` will always give you `false` since they can't be equal. Moreover you can't use `>` or `<` because it's not allowed to compare `Object` and `Integer`. Therefore you need to cast to suitable type before comparison.

```
 expression.getValue("foo.bar.![doo!=null and new Integer(doo.toString()) == 9]");
```

Also we need to check if `doo` exists that's why we need to check for `null`. `ToStringFriendlyJsonNode` can provide only string value. That's why we have to use `ToString()`. As you see native SPEL is inconvenient and too verbose because it's not supposed to be used for complex Json queries.

Comment: Using JsonPath is a less feasible option for me I guess because I'd like to use a few built-in java methods in the expressions and a few functions from spring beans. Therefore SpEL is more easier rather than having to register a lot of custom functions. Still wondering why my original expression doesn't work in SpEL + JsonPropertyAccessor.

Comment: @user1189332 I've never used Jackson API (which is under `JsonPropertyAccessor`) for queries. I even didn't know it can work with queries at all. But just for case I updated my answer and showed how to integrate JsonPath with SPEL. Hope it will be useful somehow.

Comment: @user1189332 I updated the answer. sorry, can't stop until find the solution )